# Encode and stream dynamic generated images

Tags: streaming, live, jpeg

I have an application that dynamically generates jpg files at a framerate of approximately 25 fps. Actually it generates only one jpg file which is continously updated. I would like to provide this image stream as an input to an encoder and then stream the video to a web client. I would like that the streaming is performed live, as the images are being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript and jQuery you could refresh the image at a given rate.
When the image is loaded by browser you call reloadImage() which waits 100ms and then changes the source attribute for the image to a unique path, which prevents loading the image from browser cache memory.

**HTML**

```
<img id="myImage" src="filename.jpg" onload="reloadImage()"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function reloadImage(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#myImage").attr("src",'filename.jpg? + Math.random())
    }, 100);
}
```